# IBM MQ.NET Send Message Asynchronously and Commit()

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I tried to verify the speed of using both async `Put()` and `Commit()` using the code below. The problem is that its speed is ten times slower than either using async `Put()` only or `Commit()` only, which does not make sense.

Am I missing something here?

```
class AsyncProducerWithCommit 
    {
        private MQQueueManager _queueManager;
        private MQQueue _queue;

        public void Run()
        {
            Produce();
        }


        void Produce()
        {
            Open(ConnectionMode.Write);

            PutMessage(ConvertMessageToByte(message)); 

            _queue.Close();
            _queueManager.Disconnect();
        }

        void PutMessage(byte[] messageString)
        {          
            MQMessage _message = new MQMessage();
            _message.Write(messageString);
            _message.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            _message.CharacterSet = 1208;// IbmUtf8Encoding;
            _message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;

            var putMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT    //unit of work
                                          + MQC.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;  //async

            _queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); //send message asynchronously

             _queueManager.Commit();   

        }

        void Open(ConnectionMode connectionMode)
        {
            string _queueManagerName = _appSetting.MessagingServerSetting.QueueManagerName;

            int openOptions = 0;

            switch (connectionMode)
            {
                case ConnectionMode.Read:
                    openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                    break;
                case ConnectionMode.Write:
                    openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                    break;
            }


            var properties = new Hashtable
            {
                {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
                {MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT },
                { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "192.168.1.10" },
                { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, "1415"},
                { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "LOCAL.DEF.SVRCONN" },
                {MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "user" },
                {MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pwd" }               
            };

            _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, properties);
            _queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue(QUEUE_NAME, openOptions);
        }


        public enum ConnectionMode
        {
            Read,
            Write
        }

    }
```

**Update 1**

Async Put

```
 putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;  //async
_queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); //send message asynchronously
```

Put with Commit

```
 putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;    //unit of work                                         
  _queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); 
 _queueManager.Commit();
```

QueueManager version: 8.0.0.5 on Redhat Linux 7+

MQ.NET: 8.0.0.8

Comment: Which mq queue manager version and .net dll version are you using?  Async put only impacts the put call which will return right away instead of waiting for the qmgr to respond with success or failure.   Can you show the three versions of your program and provide times for each?

Comment: Please see update 1. Again, it is ten times slower as mentioned on OP (e.g. 3 secs vs 30 secs), it is relative that matters.

Comment: another issue is that MQ.NET: 8.0.0.8 is slower than MQ.NET: 8.0.0.5. Any idea? For example, 3 secs vs 5 secs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the IBM MQ v8 Knowledge center page "[Using asynchronous put in a client application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027340_.htm)" it states:

> Normally, when an application puts a message or messages on a queue,
>   using MQPUT or MQPUT1, the application has to wait for the queue
>   manager to confirm that it has processed the MQI request. You can
>   improve messaging performance, particularly for applications that use
>   client bindings, and applications that put large numbers of small
>   messages to a queue, by choosing instead to put messages
>   asynchronously. When an application puts a message asynchronously, **the
>   queue manager does not return the success or failure of each call**, but
>   you can instead check for errors periodically.

Async put only impacts the put call which will return right away instead of waiting for the queue manager to confirm it has processed the put.

So if you have the following it would be expected to be the fastest since you would not ever be waiting for the message to write to disk.

```
_message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;  //async
_queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); //send message asynchronously
```

If you have either of these, the commit is going to wait for the message to write to disk so would be as slow as the disk write takes.  It is very possible this is slower than the above, but 3sec vs 30sec does not seem reasonable.

```
_message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT    //unit of work
                            + MQC.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;  //async
_queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); //send message asynchronously
_queueManager.Commit();
```

Or

```
_message.Persistence = MQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT;
putMessageOptions.Options  =  MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;    //unit of work                                         
_queue.Put(_message, putMessageOptions); 
_queueManager.Commit();
```

If the call with MQPMO_SYNCPOINT and MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE is 30 seconds and the call with only MQPMO_SYNCPOINT is 3 seconds, then I think there must be some sort of defect and I would suggest you open a PMR with IBM and they will likely ask you for at least a client side .NET trace and likely queue manager trace from the same time.

Comment: Great reply. How can I open PMR with IBM? Please provide the link to this? Is it possible to provide links to the explanation you provided, if possible?

Comment: Added reference to IBM KC.  PMRs would be opened with IBM under a support contract that your company would have with IBM.  There is a online site called SR that lets you do this but you have to have a IBM customer number and an IBM ID that is entitled to open these requests: https://www.ibm.com/support/servicerequest/

Comment: @pingpong let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I marked the post as answer two days ago, not sure why it does not work. I did it again now.